# Problems setting up Spring form validation

Tags: spring, maven, validation, spring-mvc

I have some problems setting up the validation in Spring MVC (4.3.9) application.
Basically, there is a simple application, with the issue isolated to one "contact" form.
Here is part of the code of the bean underlying the form:

```
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class SendMail {

    @Min(20)
    private String userName;

    @Size(min=10, max=11)
    private String message;

    private String userEmail;

    public static class CustomValidator implements Validator {
        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
            return SendMail.class.equals(clazz);
        }
        @Override
        public void validate(Object targets, Errors errors) {
            SendMail o = (SendMail) targets;

            if (o.getUserName() == null || o.getUserName().length() < 1) {
                errors.rejectValue("userName", "Empty.userName");
            }
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

and here is the part of the relevant controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/contact"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView sendEmail(@Valid SendMail sendmail, BindingResult result) {

    System.out.println("Result1: " + result.hasErrors());

    DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(sendmail);
    binder.setValidator(new SendMail.CustomValidator());
    binder.validate();
    result = binder.getBindingResult();

    System.out.println("Result2: " + result.hasErrors());
```

I get the following result:

Result1: false

Result2: true

So, the 'general' (denoted by the @Valid annotation) validation doesnt seem to work, but a manually-invoked validation does.

I googled for some time and have come across suggestions that a validation bean needs to be defined in the spring config. Unfortunately, when I add the following to my Config.java:

```
....
@Bean(name = "validator")
public Validator getValidator() {

    LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    return validator;
}
```

The application crashes with the following exception:

```
....
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ExpressionFactory
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(Unknown Source)
javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
....
```

This supposedly indicates, there is no lib with EL implementation. And here is where I'm stuck. I have tried a number of dependency (using maven) with no avail. Currently the relevant part of my pom looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have tried various set-ups, with el-impl 2.2, etc. addin el.jar to Tomcat clasppath. But no luck at all =(

What is even more starange, if you look at the exception above, the call actually goes through "javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)" before resulting in "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ExpressionFactory".

I'd be grateful for any hints on how to fix/debug the issue...

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency .

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Follow  solution [here](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-el-expressionfactory/) .

Comment: I have tried that before, as I have described in the initial question. Adding this dependency gives the same result (ClassNotFoundException). Besides, javax.el version 3 from glasfish supposedly include the implementation as well as the api

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my issue. Strange as it seems, when I added el.jar supplied with Tomcat to the classpath in catalina.sh, the validation works. It might be a distro-related issue (i'm running it on Gentoo).